# Application maintaining cache even after uninstall

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger

In my application some changes in the code is not reflecting in the application if I re-install the application. It only reflects when I uninstall and install the app again. The device I'm using is samsung F21 FE (Android version 13). It seems like device is maintaining the cache memory.

I created the viewmodel in common for all screens and which I want to use it in the baseActivity. I injected the viewmodel in the acitivities using dagger 2. Even after the application is killed the viewmodel is maintaing the old data, viewmodel is not cleared on onDestroy of baseActivity.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT6lk.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKr8f.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrAM.png)

I just tried to creating a viewmodel in common for all the BaseActivity. All activities in the application extends BaseActivity. But the viewmodel data are not cleared even after the application is killed.

Comment: Do you use ```SharedPreferences``` or ```SqLite``` database for saving data?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well, In my case it is not the issue of the device caching basically, happens with the multiple devices and emulator as well even after i remove the xml file or any code from the project as well. The android studio is maintaining the cache data in my case. I tried below steps to resolve the same.

**Step 1** :- Clean and build again.

**Step 2** :- Invalid cache and restart.

**Step 3** :- Uninstall android studio and reinstall again.

**Step 4** :- Uninstall the android studio by root. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546723/uninstall-android-studio-completely) guide or any other guide which have the commands to remove the same. Make sure all necessary things will get removed from your system like .gradle , .idea , sdk , ndk and other necessary file which contains all programs related to the android development.

**Step 5** :- System maintaining conflicts with android studio so the last option is, reset the system and install the studio again.

In my case i had done everything to resolve but the last option for me is to reset the system and i again installed the Android studio. Now it works like a charm.